# Is there a way to return the schema of a pyspark dataframe as a pythonic struct?

Tags: python, pyspark, struct

I have a Pyspark Dataframe and `df.schema.fields` returns this:

```
[StructField(Id,StringType,true),
 StructField(Sub_l1,DoubleType,true),
StructField(Detail,ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(Sub_l5,StringType,true))),false),true)]
```

Is there a way to get pyspark to return a Pythonic schema that I can store and reuse later, that looks like this:

```
 schema = StructType([
    StructField("Id", StringType(),True),
    StructField("Sub_l1", DoubleType(),True),
    StructField("Detail", ArrayType(StructType([StructField("Sub_l5", StringType(), True)]), False), True)
 ])
```

I see the latter on a lot of answers here, but I can't find a method to automatically generate a Pythonic version of the schema. Maybe I'm missing something obvious -
I've looked at `printSchema()`, `df.dtypes`, iterating through the `df.schema.fields` and getting name, dataType, etc (but that misses the nested fields), json methods, and the schema methods in the pyspark documentation. If it comes down to it, I know we can recurse through the `df.schema.fields` to get the nested fields as well, but I'm wondering if there's a direct method to return the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the schema as JSON with .ie

`schema_out: Dict[str, Any] = df.schema.jsonValue()`

and reuse it back later with

`schema_in: StructType = StructType.fromJson(schema_out)`

It contains all nested fields and can be serialized, isn't that what you're looking for ?

Comment: This is definitely an easier option than recursing, but I was wondering how to generate the specific format of schema definition with the `StructField("Id", StringType(),True)` etc. that's in the documentation